# Finding a list in list python

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I have a list that contains other lists as elements.

```
mylist=[
         [1, 'Asfoor', 'a', 'b', 'c'], 
         [2, 'deek', 'j', 'a', 'k'], 
         [3, 'bata', 'k', 'a', 'p'],
         [4,'farkha','v','m','k']
       ]
```

Now, I want to find occurrences of another list elements 'a' and 'k' in list above and need the output to be in certain format.

```
second list=['a','k']
```

For example if any element of the first list contain 'a' element of the second list then output list should be something like this:

```
['a',
     [
         [1, 'Asfoor', 'a', 'b', 'c'], 
         [2, 'deek', 'j', 'a', 'k'], 
         [3, 'bata', 'k', 'a', 'p']
     ]
]
```

And similarly, if list contains 'k' then output as below:

```
['k',
         [2, 'deek', 'j', 'a', 'k'], 
         [3, 'bata', 'k', 'a', 'p'],
         [4,'farkha','v','m','k']
]
```

Any good python way to do it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: updated my code.

Comment: @MohamedIbrahim do you want to test if `k` occurs in any of the elements, even the words e.g. would `'deek'` mean a line was included? Or do you only want it to be included if the single letter `k` occurs in the final 3 single letter strings.

Comment: no i just want occurrence of element k only in the list not withing words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
def found(a, key):
    return key in a:


keys = ['a', 'k']

final = []
for j in keys:
    final.append([j , [k for k in mylist if found(k, j)]])

# Or simply within list comprehension:
# final = [[j , [k for k in mylist if found(k, j)]] for j in keys]


print(final)
```

Output:

```
[['a',
  [[1, 'Asfoor', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
   [2, 'deek', 'j', 'a', 'k'],
   [3, 'bata', 'k', 'a', 'p']]],
 ['k',
  [[2, 'deek', 'j', 'a', 'k'],
   [3, 'bata', 'k', 'a', 'p'],
   [4, 'farkha', 'v', 'm', 'k']]]]
```

Comment: how can i do this dynamically without having to enter 'a' and 'b' keys in code manually

Comment: @MohamedIbrahim do you know how variables work?

Comment: @MohamedIbrahim, see now. I've just added a for loop with the given keys.

Comment: Thank you .now i get it clearly

Comment: Oh no. The `found()` function computes a boolean expression and then returns true or false depending on its value. Really, `found(a, key): return key in a` would suffice.

Comment: @9000 You're right :-) i just thought that it would be helpful for the OP, he is new to Python. This is why i wrote it like that. I'll edit my code.

Comment: @9000 you are right , but why both methods work

Comment: @MohamedIbrahim Both will work because `if key in a` is equal to `True` my last code will return an explicit `True`. Otherwise, `return key in a` will return a `bool = True or False`. So, better using the `return key in a`.

Comment: @MohamedIbrahim: Both are correct, but one is much shorter than the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can test if a string is in a list as follows:

```
for row in my_list:  # finding 'a' in list
    if 'a' in row:
        print(row)

for row in my_list:  # finding 'k' in list
    if 'k' in row:
        print(row)
```

Printing the row will require using "\t" (tab) and some other characters based on your desired output format

Answer (score 0):

```
print([sublist for sublist in mylist if 'a' in sublist])
# returns:
[
  [1, 'Asfoor', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
  [2, 'deek', 'j', 'a', 'k'],
  [3, 'bata', 'k', 'a', 'p']
]
```